# how to declare a external integer variable so that i can access that in in view controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, extern

i want to access variable in all views ,so how can i declare it ....

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a global variable, then in a header file that is #included by all your view controllers, put this:

```
extern int MyVariable;
```

Then in some .m file (exactly one), put this:

```
int MyVariable = 0;
```

But check out that answer about Singletons.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at *Singletons* See [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) and [here](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/)